# rsync - unexpected remote arg

Tags: rsync

I am trying to rsync a folder from remote to local but get an error below. I have looked in many threads but can't find a solution that works.

```
kong@kong-P15SM:/media/kong/Elements$ rsync -r -i /home/kong/.ssh/id_rsantu --exclude=dataset/ e130167@35.123.456.78:~/sgan-original/ ./sgan-original/
Unexpected remote arg: e130167@35.123.456.78:~/sgan-original/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to think that the option `-i` to `rsync` specifies the SSH key file like for `ssh`. It doesn't.

> -i, --itemize-changes       output a change-summary for all updates

So your command basically is

```
rsync localdir user@host:remotedir localdir
```

If you have more that one source (everything except the last parameter), they all must be local.

**Edit**

What you want to use is probably

```
rsync -r -e "ssh -i /home/kong/.ssh/id_rsantu" --exclude=dataset/ e130167@35.123.456.78:~/sgan-original/ ./sgan-original/
```

Comment: Sorry but are you saying that the command should be rsync -r --exclude=datasets/ ./sgan-original/ e130167@35.123.456.78:~/sgan-original ./sgan-original/ ?

Comment: No, I'm saying your command is equivalent to the one in the comment, and both are wrong.